# message_set of a given user in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Till now I have an model to send messages to users. I can check all the messages sent to a user or messages recieved by the user. But how do i get all the messages (sent/recieved) of a particular user? And please correct me, if my model design is wrong.
Thank you.

model.py:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='sent_set')
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='recieved_set')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s sent message: %s to %s" % (self.sender, self.description, self.recipient)

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        if self.sender == self.recipient:
            raise ValueError("Cannot message yourself")
        super(Message, self).save(**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import Q
user = request.user #or something else
Message.objects.filter(Q(sender=user)|Q(recipient=user))
```

You should read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

Comment: Just one more question though. Suppose,
`msg = Message.objects.filter(Q(sender=A)|Q(recipient=A))`, gives me all the messages sent and recieved for user 'A'. Now, how would i filter from 'msg', message sent to and recieved from a particular user 'B'.

Comment: Or if not, is there any other way around? Thanks.